# Display time index in R xts

Tags: r, xts

I want to parse csv with micro-second timed index. 
So, I wrote code like this:

```
t<-read.zoo("test", index.column = 1, sep=",",header=TRUE, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
t.xts<-as.xts(t)
```

after then, I tried to display this but I couldn't see time information on the index.

```
> t.xts[1:10,4]
           drate  
2010-09-28 " -149"
2010-09-28 " -269"
2010-09-28 " -358"
2010-09-28 " -358"
2010-09-28 " -239"
2010-09-28 " -149"
2010-09-28 " -149"
2010-09-28 " -149"
2010-09-28 " -119"
2010-09-28 " -149"
```

I tried options(digits.secs=6) but didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help if you could provide a few lines from your CSV file.  Setting `options(digits.secs=6)` works for me.  You could also try manually setting the format with `indexFormat`.

```
> x <- .xts(1:5, 1:5+runif(5))
> x
                    [,1]
1969-12-31 18:00:01    1
1969-12-31 18:00:02    2
1969-12-31 18:00:03    3
1969-12-31 18:00:04    4
1969-12-31 18:00:05    5
> indexFormat(x) <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3"
> x
                        [,1]
1969-12-31 18:00:01.915    1
1969-12-31 18:00:02.002    2
1969-12-31 18:00:03.134    3
1969-12-31 18:00:04.981    4
1969-12-31 18:00:05.204    5
> indexFormat(x) <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"
> options(digits.secs=6)
> x
                           [,1]
1969-12-31 18:00:01.914681    1
1969-12-31 18:00:02.001752    2
1969-12-31 18:00:03.134311    3
1969-12-31 18:00:04.981147    4
1969-12-31 18:00:05.204021    5
```